# debugger behavior in if, else if, else

Tags: java, debugging, if-statement

We have an application on Java 6 running on Weblogic application server 11. I am trying to debug an issue. My code is

```
if(a==0){
    //Do  A
}
else if(a==1){
    // Do B
}
else{
    // do C
}
```

My problem is that even if my if block is true and line 2 is executed still the debugger will go to line 8 in else block. 
The code on my machine and on server are synched, so no mismatch.
Please help me finding what may be wrong with my code.

Comment: Don't you get a compiler error when using an `int` assignment as a condition?

Comment: This new code is also fine. Please use copy paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to know what does the `// Do C`.

If there is an assignation:

```
if (a == 0) {
      b = 1;
} else  if (a == 1) {
      b = 0;
}
else {
      b = null;
}
```

a  typical optimization that some compilers do would be:

```
b = null;
if (a == 0) {
    b = 1;
} else if (a == 1) {
    b = 0;
}
```

And that is the bytecode executed. Let alone if the code is compiled to native by a `JIT` compiler.
So depending on your debug client and jdk you  could see crazy current  instruction lines. But it is fine as long as the state at the end of the block is the expected.

Sometimes the executions needs to close the statement. So it goes to the closing.

Make sure that no `static` values is assigned to `a` and if so, that is recompiled. Assignations of static are linked in compile time.

Comment: double value ==0;                                                     if (a==0) {
  value = 3;                                                          }                                                                 else if (a==1) {
   value = 2;                                                         } else {                                                              value=0;                                                              }                                                                      I think this is what may be happening. Thanks. Appreciate your help

Comment: that `else {}` empty generates a closing instruction. Why don't  you just remove it and see if that 'fixes' ?

Comment: do you actually see two assignations? when a == 0 value equals 3 and then value equals 0?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be:

```
if(a==0)
...
else if(a==1)
...
else
...
```

Answer (score 0):

don't forget that `=` is an assignment and `==` is a comparison - in your case, you're assigning the value and then checking the result of the assignment, NOT performing a comparison.

Simply change

```
if(a=0){
    //Do A
}
else if(a=1){
    // Do B
```

to

```
if(a==0){
    //Do A
}
else if(a==1){
    // Do B
```

Comment: I am sorry. That was a typo when I wrote for help. In my actual code the condition is different. I have edited my initial post already. This problem still persists. Thanks

Comment: @Whoever downvoted - why exactly? It was a correct answer to the posted question...